# android image load dynamic openGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

i'm in trouble, why my loaded imagenot work perfectly. I have a renderer class, a model class and a piece class. In rendere class I generate models, and every model have a piece property. In rendere class

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {


    // preparation
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    loadGLTexture(gl, context);
    models=new HashMap<Identity,Model>();
    for(int i=-9;i<10;i+=2){
        for(int j=-8;j<10;j+=4){
            models.put(new Identity(i,j), new Model(j,i,0f,w,h));
            models.get(new Identity(i,j)).getPiece().setImageBuffer(imageBuffer);
            models.get(new Identity(i,j)).getPiece().setTextures(textures);   
        }
    }

        // Load the texture for the square
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            //Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Enable Smooth Shading
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);    //Black Background
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Enables Depth Testing
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             //The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);

}
public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.tree2);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        // generate one texture pointer
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        // ...and bind it to our array

        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        // create nearest filtered texture

        imageBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bitmap.getHeight() * bitmap.getWidth() * 4);
        imageBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        byte buffer[] = new byte[4];
        for(int i = 0; i < bitmap.getHeight(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < bitmap.getWidth(); j++)
            {
                int color = bitmap.getPixel(j, i);
                buffer[0] = (byte)Color.red(color);
                buffer[1] = (byte)Color.green(color);
                buffer[2] = (byte)Color.blue(color);
                buffer[3] = (byte)Color.alpha(color);
                imageBuffer.put(buffer);
            }
        }
        imageBuffer.position(0);
        gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageBuffer);    
        // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
        bitmap.recycle();
     }
```

The draw function:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
     // define the color we want to be displayed as the "clipping wall"
    gl.glClearColor(_red, _green, _blue, 1.0f);
    // reset the matrix - good to fix the rotation to a static angle

    gl.glLoadIdentity();   
    // clear the color buffer to show the ClearColor we called above...
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    for(Model model:models.values()){
        model.draw(gl);    
    }

 }
```

In model class I draw colored hexagon;

```
public void draw(GL10 gl){

     gl.glLoadIdentity();
     gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _vertexBuffer);
     gl.glColor4f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1f); 
     gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, _nrOfVertices, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, _indexBuffer);
     if(piece!=null){
         piece.draw(gl);
     }
 }
```

In piece class

```
public void draw(GL10 gl){

     gl.glLoadIdentity();
    // gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            // bind the previously generated texture
            gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);
    // gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
            gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, 32, 32, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageBuffer);
            // gl.glTexSubImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, 32, 32, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageBuffer);
            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
            gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

            // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
            gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0,4);

 }
```

I set the vertexBuffer and textureBuffer in the constructor.
I don't know witch gl method where to use, in most tutorials use the image only once. 
Why my png lost the transparentcy, why I can't see the models' hexagons.

It started to be complicate for me :(

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGL ES 2.0 my image loading code looks like this:

```
 final int[] textureObjectIds = new int[1];
    glGenTextures(1, textureObjectIds, 0);

    if (textureObjectIds[0] == 0) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Could not generate a new OpenGL texture object.");
        return 0;
    } 

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    // Read in the resource
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        context.getResources(), resourceId, options);

    if (bitmap == null) {
        if(GameLogger.ON)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Resource ID " + resourceId + " could not be decoded.");
        }
        glDeleteTextures(1, textureObjectIds, 0);
        return 0;
    } 

    // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObjectIds[0]);

    // Set filtering: a default must be set, or the texture will be
    // black.
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
    bitmap.recycle();

    // Unbind from the texture.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Hope that might help you.